# Is there any problem when ExecutorService gives every time a new thread pool?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice, java-threads

I have following code, which is executed each time for different number of threads:

```java
class Worker<T> {
  public void process() {
      System.out.pritnln("Test");
  }
}

class Processor {
  private void doStuff(final Collection<Worker<V>> col) {
    final int size = col.size();
    if (size > 0) {
      final ExecutorService threads = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(col.size());
      for (Worker<V> w : col) {
        threads.submit(() -> w.process());
      }
      threads.shutdown();
    }
  }
}
```

Which is printing every time in new identifier of polls:

> (pool-66-thread-1) Test
>
> (pool-66-thread-2) Test
>
> (pool-67-thread-1) Test
>
> (pool-68-thread-1) Test
>
> (pool-68-thread-3) Test
>
> (pool-68-thread-2) Test

I wonder if this is the common behavior, or at some point there is a memory leak and It will explode. Shouldn't it reuse previous `pools`?

How I see things, those previous pools are already `shutdown` thanks to the `threads.shutdown()` call

Comment: Why are you surprised when a function named "new...ThreadPool" creates a new thread pool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder if this is the common behaviour, or at some point there is memory leak and will explode. Shouldn't it reuse previous pools?

Well, you are explicitly creating new pools all the time.

```
// this creates a new pool
final ExecutorService threads = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(col.size());
```

As for memory leaks, since you are shutting down your pools, that should be fine (but you should do it `finally` to be safe in case there are exceptions).

If you want to re-use the pool (which makes total sense), you should make `threads` an instance variable of your `Processor` (and make sure that `Processor implements AutoCloseable` and you shutdown the `threads` in the close method).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Thilo, The problem about reusing pools is that every time I execute it, I might need different number of threads, some times 1 thread is enough, maybe later I need 5, and at some stress point, I might need to have 3 thousand threads. I did not find good Idea to keep in memory a huge thread pool of 3 thousand threads, or even bigger, since I can not really determine the number of threads. (It comes from Kafka received events from multiple devices)

Comment: Hi @Mayday. It sounds like you might want to look into ThreadPoolExecutor where you can specify the core size (minimum alive threads) and keep alive time (how long a thread is idle for before being terminated). https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

Comment: It also seems very unlikely that you can really gain anything from 3000 threads. Determine a reasonable amount based on the work load and machine capacity, then size the thread pool accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `Executors.newFixedThreadPool()` in your function, which creates a new thread pool.

This is not **wrong** as such, but it is uncommon, and goes against a lot of the motivation behind using thread pools. A more standard approach would be to create a single thread pool in your `Processor` class, and dispatch jobs to it, as such:

```
class Processor {
    private final ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadExecutor(count);

    private void doStuff() {
        ...
        ...
        service.submit(() -> w.process());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @cameron1024, Please, feel free to check the comment I posted in the other answer please, So I do not repeat it here :)

Comment: I have read your comment, you should create it with the maximum number you anticipate. They will consume limited resources when they are not running, especially on modern systems. Remember, premature optimization is evil. Write sensible code first, then optimize only if there are obvious performance problems.

Answer (score 0):

Idea of having a thread pool is to restrict the number of threads you are creating and reusing the threads which already created, to avoid unnecessary congestion processing tons of threads at a given time and make it more efficient. Now the issue with your code is it is not restricting the number of threads nor reusing. Since you are only do some printing you may not see congestion but if you add more processing in your worker and keep invoke it in parallel then you will see a drastic latency in getting the processing done.